# A way to identify and match cards in memory game

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a memory matching game where two cards are flipped and then checked if they match. If they match, then they remain flipped, otherwise flipped over. But I am stuck on finding a way to identify the cards to match them.

```
class Card
{
    List<int> IDs = new List<int>();
    List<PictureBox> pictureBoxes = new List<PictureBox>;

    public void addPictureBox(PictureBox pb)
    {
        pictureBoxes.Add(pb);
    }


    public void addInt(int numberOfCards)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfCards; i++)
        {
            IDs.Add(i);
        }
    }

}
```

So far I made this card class to store each picturebox in a list and also made a list of integers to identify them. What is a method where I link the two together?

Comment: The integer in the *integer list* is the index into the *picturebox list*.

Comment: If I didn't want to use the Tag method, what is one way I can approach it?

Comment: Your OO design needs work. Why would a single Card contain a 'numberOfCards'? Your Card class should only contain properties and methods that belong to the card. Try rewriting the Card class to contain one picture, and remove the rest for now. Then write a Board class that has a property of `List<Card>` (or you could go with a two-dimensional array of type Card). Write a method for the Board class that populates that List with Card objects, giving them pictures (2 of each, right?). Once your design makes sense, the rest should be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Well make a class that has a picturebox and an int. And make a list of this class:

```
public class Card{
    public Picturebox pic;
    public int Id; 
}

List<Card> Cards= new List<Card>();

  public void addInt(int numberOfCards)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfCards; i++)
        {
            Cards.Add(new Card(){
                  pictureBoxes= pb,
                  id = i
            });
        }
    }
```

Now you can access each card like: `card.Id` and `card.Pic`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to better design the `Card` class to effectively represent a card, using [SOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principles (i.e. a card shouldn't have a list of `PictureBox`, instead it should have a `Image` property representing it's face).

The `Card` class should be something like this:

```
public class Card {
    public int ID {
        get; set;
    }
    public Image Face {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Then there should be a class named `Board` with a `List<Card>`, filling this property on initialization with all the cards. For simplicity sake, you could match the cards using a `Dicionaty<int, int>` filled with all the ID's as the keys and the respective matches as the values, so you can call the Dictionary `TryGetValue` to check if some id is a match for another id:

```
public class Board {
    public Board() {
        InitializeCards();
    }

    private readonly List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> cardsDictionary= new Dictionary<int, int>();

    private void InitializeCards() {
        cards.Clear();
        cardsDictionary.Clear();
        // Fill the cards list with the cards, and the cardsDictionary with all the ID's and each match, using the cardsDisctionary.Add(someCard.ID, someOtherCard.ID)
    }
    private bool IsMatch(int id, int matchId) {
        int realMatch;
        if (cardsDictionary.TryGetValue(id, out realMatch)) {
            return matchId == realMatch;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

To represent the cards visually, in your form class you can create another dictionary with the key being the ids of cards and the values the PictureBoxs, that way would be easy to use the created classes to do your game.

Of course there are more advanced ways of doing this, but i tried to answer with a simple one.